# jboss wildfly datasource connection failing - No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, datasource, wildfly-8

I have a jboss wildfly server connected to a mysql database via a datasource configured on the app server.

It hapens some time that the mysql database is not accessible for an amount of time (netework problem etc...), when the mysql is not accessible I receive in logs the message :

```
09:42:30,015 ERROR [org.jboss.seam.async.AsynchronousExceptionHandler] (4pm_services_QuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Exception thrown whilst executing asynchronous call: java.
lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

this is expected as thy mysql is not available at that moment, the porblem is that when the mysql server comes online again the error still persists, and the jboss server is unable to get a valid from the connection pool.

I have:
wildfly 8.1
mysql 5.5
use JPA for comunicating with database

here is the datasource configuration:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/services_DS" pool-name="fourPmDSServices" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.110:3306/FOUR_PM__SERVICES?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <new-connection-sql>select 1</new-connection-sql>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>*********</user-name>
                        <password>*********</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>10</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

And here is the complete stack trace of the error:

```
00:00:00,017 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (4pm_services_QuartzScheduler_Worker-2) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
00:00:00,018 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (4pm_services_QuartzScheduler_Worker-2) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/services_DS
00:00:00,018 ERROR [org.jboss.seam.async.AsynchronousExceptionHandler] (4pm_services_QuartzScheduler_Worker-2) Exception thrown whilst executing asynchronous call: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.QuartzJobBase.executeInternal(QuartzJobBase.java:91) [4pm_services-ejb.jar:]
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.QuartzJobBase.schedule(QuartzJobBase.java:76) [4pm_services-ejb.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor98.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_32]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.async.AsynchronousInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.emailSender.MailChecker_$$_javassist_seam_2.schedule(MailChecker_$$_javassist_seam_2.java) [4pm_services-ejb.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_32]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.async.AsynchronousInvocation$1.process(AsynchronousInvocation.java:62) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.async.Asynchronous$ContextualAsynchronousRequest.run(Asynchronous.java:80) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.async.AsynchronousInvocation.execute(AsynchronousInvocation.java:44) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.async.QuartzDispatcher$QuartzJob.execute(QuartzDispatcher.java:243) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) [quartz.jar:1.6.0]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529) [quartz.jar:1.6.0]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1389) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.emailSender.MailChecker.checkQueue(MailChecker.java:37) [4pm_services-ejb.jar:]
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.emailSender.MailChecker.execute(MailChecker.java:26) [4pm_services-ejb.jar:]
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.QuartzJobBase$TransactionalWork.work(QuartzJobBase.java:144) [4pm_services-ejb.jar:]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Work.workInTransaction(Work.java:61) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.2.Final]
    at si.arctur.fourPmServices.scheduleJobs.QuartzJobBase.executeInternal(QuartzJobBase.java:89) [4pm_services-ejb.jar:]
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/services_DS
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446) [hibernate-core.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/services_DS
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:390)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:377)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getTransactionNewConnection(AbstractPool.java:495)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:374)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
    ... 54 more
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you need to define a flush strategy of you failed connections.
check the "flush-strategy" param.

A good point to start is here:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration

They reference this XSD:
http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/schema/datasources_1_1.xsd

And the XSD decription is here:
http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.2/en-US/html_single/index.html#deployingds

In your case I would try to figure out the network issues.
Independently of this. I would in your case (with bad connection issues) flush my complete connection pool:
flush-strategy => EntirePool

good luck on fixing such an odd issue

Comment: tnx for the info, we suspect that it happens when the vpn which is between the app server location and the DB location fails. Don't ask why there is a VPN in between :) we plan to merge those two locations in future...anyway tnx for the info it looks very interesting

Comment: do not forget the bounty ;-)
regarding the VPN, maybe I can help too... Best is to open a new question and provide the vpn details there.

Answer (score 4):

**What Does The Message No Managed Connection Available mean?**

It means that all possible connections to the db are in use and/or that a thread has timed-out waiting for a connection to open up.

**Possible solutions:**

Increase your connection pool size

Add

**`<max-pool-size>whatever</max-pool-size>`**

to your -ds.xml file to increase

the number of connections available. The default is 20

There is an attribute

**MaxConnectionsInUse**

viewable on the jmx-console against the

ManagedConnectionPool

that can help you understand how many connections you really need.

Tell your threads to wait longer for a connection to open up

Add

**`<blocking-timeout-millis>whatever</blocking-timeout-millis>`**

to your -ds.xml file to increase the length of time to wait. The default is 30000 (5000 before JBoss-3.2.4) milli-seconds.

Make sure you are properly closing open connections

Comment: Tnx for the info I don't need as many connections in that application it has usually only one user. I also use managed transactions by EJB container and a hibernate for ORM, so I'm not manualy opening an closing connections. Anyway I will try to increase the max-pool-size and the blocking-timout-mills, mybe it will help...tnx for the info again

Comment: @simonC: increasing the connection pool may not help you. Since you have already opened connections, which are trying to get the connection back to the database. So it will only increase the amount of open connections to the server.

Comment: Increasing the connection pool will only fill up new connections which cannot reach the database. And as soon as the connections are back, your database will have to do a lot of work... I am an admin and would limit the applications concurrent threads/connections to the database. So the issue would be much more problematic on the jboss side.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue as well.  However, my connection worked briefly and then stopped working after a number of requests.  It turned out to be an unclosed connection to the database, which caused connections to be consumed and eventually exhausting the connection pool.  Simply increasing the connection pool size will only delay the eventual error.  You'll need to identify where you not correctly closing your connection in order to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

debug="true" error="true" in the JCA in standalone-ha.xml

Verify that  exists in the jca subsystem and set debug="true".

          ...
          
          ...
       
Then in server.log it will write if any connections are not closing with stack trace of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I fixed with the answer that @Harsh said. I increased the maxpoolsize from 20 to 100 and the problem is gone.

Comment: In which file did you increased maxpoolsize?

Answer (score -2):

**Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])**

This message says, that configured pool cannot provide any connection within configured timeout of 3sec (3000msec). Either your pool is too low or your connections are not closed after usage, perhaps increasing the pool size will work.

Also check the connection close from JBoss.

Comment: As you are working with VPN I think the issue is network communication failure. For "jboss server is unable to get a valid from the connection pool":- when connectivity is working fine some successful connections were maintained in the data-source pool of the server. Once this link   disconnects and try to connect again this data-source validates existing pooled connections before handing it out. I think that's why Jboss is not validated again.

Answer (score -2):

**Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/services_DS**

It seem that problem is related to some database table and java configuration like hbm.xml. For each Table Type parameter the java api opens a connection to database or due to some other environment configuration.

Please refer following link here you will get same problem with solution.

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/211940

http://www.coderanch.com/t/556721/JBoss/Jboss-Datasource-configured-correctly-unable